# CodeMap does not Sequentially Arrange Method Calls

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-map

I have a legacy code which has a method containing a lot of code, the method makes call to tons of other methods too. To visualize I right clicked on the method name and from context menu selected

> Show Related Items on Code Map --> Show Methods This Calls

I was hoping to visualize that code map will display methods being called in sequence but I don't see that, to visualize, see the image below.

[image]

Is there a way to make code map show calling methods in sequence by selecting some option in Layout?